# Not able to pass the result from a SQL Query to a method in JAVA

Tags: java, sql

This is my first time using Java and i got confused.

I created this method:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, "323");
```

which pass in a harcoded value, in this case it is 323, right?

My getResultInMapList looks like this:

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> getResultInMapList(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password,String sqlQuery, Object... params) throws
    SQLException, IOException {

        try {
            createConn(urlString,driverr,usernameString,password);
            if (params == null) {
            return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler());
      } else {
          return run.query(conn, sqlQuery, new MapListHandler(), params);
    }
     } catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
         return null;
     } finally {
    closeConn();
     }
   }
```

The problem is that i don't want to pass a harcoded value anymore, instead of that i want to pass the result of a SQL Query.

SQL Query:

```
sqlQuery2: "select name from fake_table" (it is just an example)
```

---

Expected result:

```
List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, sqlQuery2);
```

The problem is that i don't know how to modify my getResultInMapList in order to make it work.

I tried doing something like this:

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> getResultInMapList(String urlString, String driverr, String usernameString, String password,String sqlQuery, sqlQuery2)
```

but then the "params" does not exist anymore

What should i do in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run sqlQuery2 first, store the results in a different List, then convert the List to an array:

```
List<Object> paramList = new ArrayList<>();

try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery2);
    while (results.next()) {
        paramList.add(results.getString(1));
    }
}

Object[] params = paramList.toArray();
```

Whether `results.getString(1)` is actually the right column to retrieve will depend on your database and your query.  I assume `sqlQuery2` only retrieves the data it needs to retrieve.

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying! Which parameter should i pass? Object[] params?

Comment: I mean, in here: This is my first time using Java and i got confused.

List<Map<String, Object>>resultSet= getResultInMapList(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password, sqlQuery, xxxx)

Comment: Yes, the `params` in the above code can be used exactly as you’ve been using `params` in your existing code.

Comment: Should i import Statement and ResultSet from java.sql, right?

Comment: Correct, they are classes in the java.sql package.

Comment: I'm checking this out, pal. Sorry, i'm kinda new to Java and everything seems different :)

Comment: I'm getting this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "package.Product.conn" is null
 at package.Product.main(Product.java:129)

Comment: If `conn` is null, none of your other code will work either.  You have to assign a value to `conn`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it for details.

Comment: it is working above, i have connected to the database :/

Comment: I think i have to specifiy something like this: createConn(urlString,driverr,usernameString,password); otherwise conn in main is null

Comment: i solved it by adding createConn(urlString, driverr, usernameString, password); :)