# How to handle Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert (Selenium & JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium

I want to handle this exception in JAVA & SELENIUM

In my code i did this:

```
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept(); 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btnGoConfirm\"]")).click();
```

The problem is that sometimes the popup does not appear and the exception in thrown because it cannot click on anything at all, do you get me?

How should i handle this particular situation?

Comment: Maybe you can add those 2 lines into a try/catch block. In the try block add those 2 lines, in the except block do nothing. If alert appears it will click the button, if not your script will continue.

Comment: Hey @JakyRuby Jaky, thanks for commenting!. how would you do it in this case? I'm kinda confused

Comment: Maybe the answer could be a solution

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
try {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept(); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btnGoConfirm\"]")).click();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("I got an exception, but it is only because alert did not appear, so I continue with my script")
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna try it, Jaky. I don't want the problem to stop running if the pop up does not appear

Comment: Jaky, could you please take a look at this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392304/not-able-to-pass-the-result-from-a-sql-query-to-a-method-in-java

Comment: Actually I am not a Java developer, I just though that maybe this could help you with your script, but I can not help you a lot with Java...with selenium maybe a little bit more.

Comment: Alright, pal :)